# BootCamp, can't partition SSD

Tags: macos, bootcamp, ssd, partition

I've upgraded my OS X to the latest Yosemite GM Candidate and cannot for the life of me figure out how to partition my SSD for BootCamp. Here are some screenshots of the problem:

[image]

And when i try to partition from Disk Utility:

[image]

What is the problem and can it be solved? I read somewhere something about needing to wipe my hard drive and start over with a fresh OS X install, but i really would prefer not to do that, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

P.S:
I've tried verifying disk permissions, and repairing in recovery mode. Nothing worked.

MacBook Pro with Retina display, OS X Yosemite (10.10)

**diskutil list** output

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 D2BB45DB-C690-47B2-BFF0-E0A5D812EE6A
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.2 GB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WININSTALL              8.2 GB     disk2s1
```

**diskutil cs list** output

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 312C0A5B-AC3E-4008-895F-6EDFDD386825
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         120473067520 B (120.5 GB)
    Free Space:   35721216 B (35.7 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 5292E607-3F97-46C0-8E92-97BC853367D5
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120473067520 B (120.5 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 736C4179-B89A-4EBE-90C7-F0CE4705D2B3
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume D2BB45DB-C690-47B2-BFF0-E0A5D812EE6A
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          120101797888 B (120.1 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: please do a 'diskutil list' & 'diskutil cs list' with Terminal.app and add the output to your question. Yosemite GM or Release?

Comment: @klanomath Yosemite GM, the latest Update provided by apple. I also tried this with the release, however same result.

Comment: @klanomath I've added the diskutil command output to the question.

Comment: disk2 is a thumb drive with Win7/8/8.1?

Comment: Windows 7. It's 8GB and has the Bootcamp installed windows support software. Ready to boot from once i have a windows partition made.

Comment: Do you have a time machine backup?

Comment: no, but i could make one

Comment: i think the problem is: 'Revertible: No' (4th line from below) in the diskutil cs list output. With a yes it would be easy probably

Comment: Ok, well i don't mind just wiping the disk, no important files are on here that i need. Do i need to format the HD or something similar?

Comment: in my eyes the core storage item (Logical Volume Group etc) prevents the creation of the 2nd (boot camp) partition. I'm just reading a lengthy thread related to that: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1741742

Comment: Ah, what if i downgraded to an OS X version that doesn't use core storage, made the partition, then upgraded?

Comment: Before erasing the disk i would try: 'diskutil cs revert disk1' in the terminal app. Do you have a second computer to visit apple.stackexchange?

Comment: Yes i do, just tried the revert command:


*Started CoreStorage operation on disk1 Macintosh HD
Error: -69666: This Core Storage operation is not allowed on a sparse logical volume group*

Comment: a successful operation may take 3-5 minutes then restart the mac and enter 'diskutil list' and Apple_CoreStorage should be replaced by Apple_HFS

Comment: We need a chat room ;-)

Comment: Should we move it to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18150/discussion-between-klanomath-and-thatguy343).

Comment: Successful operation of reverting?

Comment: Is your SSD an Apple Fusion Drive?

Comment: SSD, but this was resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Mac Book Retina was originally delivered with Mountain Lion. The upgrade history contains Mavericks, several Yosemite DPs and finally the Yosemite GM Candidate.

One of the Yosemite Developer Previews transformed the previous `Apple_HFS partition` into a `Logical Volume Group`.

The (only) Logical Volume is not revertible:

[image]

The Boot Camp assistant can't modify the partition map and shrink such a LVG to free up some unallocated space for a Windows installation on a hard disk.

The only possibility (we found) to solve the problem is a complete reinstall:

1. Backup all your data
2. Disconnect all external hard drives
3. Restart into `Internet Recovery Mode` by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
   (alternatively you may use a Mavericks or Mountain Lion Install Thumb Drive)
4. start `Terminal` from the menubar/utilities
5. enter following command at the Terminal prompt:

   > diskutil cs list
6. Copy the Logical Volume Group (LVG) alphanumeric UUID of your CoreStorage volume. The LVG UUID should be the first listed. In the above example the alphanumeric is:
   312C0A5B-AC3E-4008-895F-6EDFDD386825.
7. Run the following command:

   > diskutil cs delete UUID

   According to the number found above it would be:

   > diskutil cs delete 312C0A5B-AC3E-4008-895F-6EDFDD386825

   This will delete your CoreStorage volume and your Recovery HD and reformat it as a simple HFS+ volume.
8. Quit `Terminal`
9. In the now opening window choose `Disk Utility` and format/partition/rename the internal drive. Choose `1 Partition`, `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` and GUID partition table (available with the `option` button). Quit `Disk Utility`.
10. Now choose 'Reinstall Mac OS X'
11. The originally shipped OS X will be downloaded and installed
12. Set up your Mac
13. Download and install Mavericks from the App Store
14. Start `Boot Camp Assistant`, repartiton your Mac and install Windows
15. Download and install Yosemite from the App Store

At step 10 one may boot alternatively to a Mavericks or Mountain Lion Install Thumb Drive if available and install the respective OS X.

Starting into `Recovery Mode` at step 3 doesn't help because it's impossible to delete the LGV then.

Comment: :) thank you again, this all worked perfectly and i now have 2 partitions (pc,mac).

Answer (score 2):

OP, you can run the following command "diskutil cs revert" in Terminal. It will non-destructively revert Yosemite's unnecessary CoreStorage volume setup into a "normal" (non-CoreStorage) setup. I had to run in on a few of the dev previews. You may have to run it as root.

Comment: I had a similar though not identical issue as the questioner. I could partition my drive in Disk Utility but Bootcamp could do nothing with it, not even remove the partition I created. This ultimately solved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1):

@klanomath answer is like killing a mosquito with a surface to air missile (SAM) that cost an arm and a leg.

The problem is simple: there is an error in your disk. I had the same issue, exactly. I will recommend you first check if there are errors on your disk, repair it and try Boot Camp once again.

How to Check for Errors and Repair your HD:

> First, you have to shut down your Mac. Then, turn it on and
>   immediately hold down Command + S to enter Single User Mode. Now, type
>   in the following code into the command prompt interface:
>
> /sbin/fsck -fy
>
> Then, press Enter on your keyboard. That command checks and repairs
>   inconsistencies in file systems that might prevent you from
>   partitioning your drive. Once that has been completed, type in this
>   code:
>
> reboot
>
> Hit Enter and your Mac will restart as usual.
>
> Now, try running Boot Camp Assistant again to install Windows. You
>   should not receive the previous error and will be able to run the
>   installation without any hiccup.

Reference: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/bootcamp-assistant-cannot-partition/

90% of the time, this will work. If it doesn't, you can then order for SAM from Lockheed Martin on Northrup Grumman by following the advice of @klanomath

Answer (score 0):

You have file vault enabled on that partition, you cannot resize a core storage volume without first decrypting the drives contents. Goto System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Filevault, hit the lock icon on the bottom left and enter your login credentials, push the button labeled Turn Off File Vault, after confirming, you should see a progress bar showing the status of the drive decryption. Once the drive is completely decrypted you can resize the partitions.

This will completely decrypt your drives data, so once you are satisfied with your new partition setup and commit them to disk, go ahead and turn file vault back on. Also note the decryption process is not quick, it make take over a day. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, according to the asker file vault never was enabled: "Encryption Type: None"

Comment: @klanomath You are correct, I incorrectly assumed from a quick glance at the partition scheme the op was using File Vault. Apparently Yosemite creates a core storage volume by default even though it may not be needed for anything. My answer is not relevant to the op's question.