# Install or Remove Windows 7 or later version - this option is Not avaiable how do i Fix it?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, install

Install or Remove Windows 7 or later version - this option is Not available Check On My iMac Screenshort ... How Do i Fix it ?
[image]

Comment: Do you have FileVault enabled? Have you modified your disc partitions manually?

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list` entered in `Terminal.app` to your question.

Comment: after that what do i do .... do u know any commend ??? Can you tell me complete Step ???

Comment: @AndrewRozarioPhotography The output may help us detect errors and finally post an answer. Just open "Terminal.app" (in /Applications/Utilities/), enter "diskutil list" and hit the enter key on your keyboard. Copy the output and paste it into your question: [example](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152898/bootcamp-cant-partition-ssd/153079#153079)