# Boot Camp disk can not be partitioned

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on my Mid-2012 MacBook Air running OS X 10.10.5 "Yosemite".

When creating the partition, Boot Camp stops after a short while displaying that the partition can not be created.

I have found the following earlier post: [BootCamp, can't partition SSD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152898/bootcamp-cant-partition-ssd)
but my disk does not show a core storage volume and I am hoping that I do not need to reinstall the OS.

Here is the output from Terminal running diskutil list:

[image]

Any ideas what else could be preventing Boot Camp from creating the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need to erase anything. Would you mind rebooting to Recovery HD and re-running Disk Utility to repair the drive? If that works, try again and see if you can get an error from Console or system.log if it fails you again. I'll dig into where BootCamp might log the failure in the mean time.

Comment: THANKS! Disk Utility repaired an invalid directory item and after that everything worked out fine :)